# Can't seem to make my scene scroll horizontally automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, spritebuilder

I am trying to make a game that consist of a "hero" that runs endlessly and basically has to avoid obstacles and as he avoids these obstacles he receives point and I am trying to make this game in Sprite Builder which I am not so good in yet and having a hard time coding for it.

Basically this is what I have so far:

```
static const CGFloat scrollSpeed = 0.1;

@implementation level
{
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
    CCSprite *_guy;
}

- (void)update:(CCTime)delta 
{
    _guy.position = ccp(_guy.position.x + delta * scrollSpeed, _guy.position.y);
    _physicsNode.position = ccp(_physicsNode.position.x - (scrollSpeed *delta), _physicsNode.position.y);
}

- (void)didLoadFromCCB 
{
    // tell this scene to accept touches
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
}

- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    //whenever the screen is tapped, this will happen
    [self guyJump];
}

- (void)guyJump {
    //makes the guy jump   
}
```

But then I am also receiving this error in the console:

```
CCBReader: Couldn't find member variable: _physicsNode
CCBReader: Couldn't find member variable: _guy
```

[image]

**HOW I SOLVED IT !**

***Make sure that in SpriteBuilder:***

1. level is the custom class of your CCScene root node
2. Your CCSprite and CCPhysicsNode is marked as Doc root var and the correct name is
   marked, also it should not be a custom class
3. Do a File->Clean Cache
4. Press the Publish button

***Make sure that in XCode***

5. You have a custom class called level
6. In level you have an ivar declared

   `@implementation level
       {
           CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
           CCSprite *_guy;
       }`
7. Do a Product->Clean
8. Run your project

Comment: It is better you write true answer and check it as an answer if you have it. Mate It isn't very good to write solved to your question's title. Good day.

Comment: I answered my own question ..... @yucel bayram

Comment: Thanks, you know it is important for people who have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace these lines of code:

```
@implementation level
{
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
    CCSprite *_guy;
}
```

with:

```
@interface level ()
{
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
    CCSprite *_guy;
}

@implementation level
```

Comment: I am still getting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

***Make sure that in SpriteBuilder:***

1. level is the custom class of your CCScene root node
2. Your CCSprite and CCPhysicsNode is marked as Doc root var and the correct name is
   marked, also it should not be a custom class
3. Do a File->Clean Cache
4. Press the Publish button

***Make sure that in XCode***

1. You have a custom class called level
2. In level you have an ivar declared

   `@implementation level
       {
           CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
           CCSprite *_guy;
       }`
3. Do a Product->Clean
4. Run your project